# Set true/false value to a Knockout observable variable using Knockout-Validation library

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there any way to set a Knockout observable variable to true/false values if the is a validation error?

My code:

```
self.newProductPriceEntry = {
    Quantity: ko.observable("").extend({ required: true }).extend({ digit: true }),
    Price: ko.observable("").extend({ required: true }).extend({ digit: true })
}
```

For example, if the user doesn't insert the **Quantity** to set it to false, or if the value inserted is not a number to set it to false also.

Comment: That seems to be a wrong design. Quantity should be a number and not a Boolean value. The right way would be to have an extender add a child observable that says something like `Quantity.hasErrors()`. Below is a link that clearly explains it. See the live example 2 http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it this way